# Extend plain background in a video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, command-line-arguments

Is there any easier way to achieve this?, I'd like to make a .bat file that modify 148 videos that are 3840x2160

They belong to the [COLORFUL platform video set 1.8.0](https://forums.launchbox-app.com/files/file/1958-colorful-platform-video-set/)

Every video has a system or console in the middle of it and it has a plain color as background. I want to keep the resolution, 3840x2160 but I need to displace the image a 15% to the right so it will be neccesary to fill the left area with the same color it's being use as color of the background.

This is a snapshot from one of these videos:

[Snapshot of the original video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJHfp.jpg)

The result should be something like this:

[Snapshot of the video I'd like to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tz9Ix.jpg)

So far I was trying lot of things with no success, I maybe did it harder than it is really. I did a first script that crop the video:

```
for %%X in (*.mp4) do .\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -threads 4 -i "%%X" -filter:v "crop=2688:ih" -c:a copy -threads 4 "second_script\%%X"
```

The new video will be stored in the second_script folder, then there is a second script that will use ffmpeg to export a picture from the video and magick.exe will help me to identify the color, after that it will use ffmpeg again to add an are of that color, but ... for some reason I don't know the color result is not the same

```
for %%X in (*.mp4) do (
..\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -threads 4 -i "%%X" -vf "select=eq(n\,100)" -vframes 1 %%~nX.png

magick.exe .\%%~nX.png -format "%%[hex:u.p{0,0}]" info: > temp.txt

for /f "delims=" %%i in (temp.txt) do (
..\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -threads 4 -i "%%X" -filter_complex "[0]pad = w=3840 : h=ih: x=3840-2688 : y=0 : color=#%%i" -movflags +faststart  -c:a copy -threads 4 "final\%%X"
)

)
```

What I get is something like this:

[Final result, it doesn't look like I expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8xGa.jpg)

Would there be any easy way to do this? any recommendation is really appreciate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in one command, like this

`ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "split=2[bg][img];[bg]trim=end_frame=1,crop=128:ih,scale=3840:2160:flags=neighbor,setsar=1[bg];[bg][img]overlay=w=0.15*W:h=0" -c:a copy out.mp4`

Comment: You master it! :D
I needed to change:
`[img]overlay=w=0.15*W:h=0`
by
`[bg][img]overlay=0.15*W:0`
And I changed crop value from 128 to `crop=3264` but all the rest works like a charm.

Comment: @Maiki It's true that he _"master it"_... Gyan makes FFmpeg.